# Перегрузка операнда ++

Tags: c++

Необходимо перегрузить операцию ++ как движение по списку. В чём ошибка?

```
template <class M>

    Node<M>* operator ++ (Node<M> &p)
    {
        p = p->next;
        return p;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
    
        Node<int>* pbeg = first(15);
        Node<int>* pend = pbeg;
        add(&pend, 2);
        add(&pend, 3);
        Node<int>* pv = pbeg;
        cout << pv->data << '\t';
        ++pv;
        cout << pv->data << '\t';
```

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузить таким образом этот оператор как вы хотите не получится, т.к придется писать

```
Node* operator++()
{
    this = next; 
    return next;
}
```

а это не верно. `this` это prvalue (9.3.2)[стандарта](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) и ему нельзя ничего присваивать. Подробнее про prvalue можно прочитать [здесь](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

А если нужно сделать объект который бы указывал на ваш `Node<M>` и для которого был бы переопределен оператор `++`, то нужно сделать отдельный класс для этого, как это сделано в стандартной библиотеке С++, там есть [std::iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator)

Comment: Это не придирки! 1) Почему `const type& operator++();` возвращает `const` ссылку? 2) Перегрузка инкримента/декримента может быть внешней функцией (не методом). Тогда ей нужен аргумент.

Comment: Да действительно, в этом пункте я ошибся. Поправил ответ